# sending more than 65536 byte with TCP applications

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, ip

I would like to know, how can two easy programs that transfer a text file from the sender to the receiver, send more than 65536 Byte (the maximum size of an IP packet).
This is the sender:

```
 FILE *fp=fopen("file_to_send.txt","r");
 char msg[65536];
 len = strlen(msg)+1;
 nwrite=0;
 printf ("write()\n");
 fflush(stdout);
 do{
   n=write(socketfd, &(msg[nwrite]), len-nwrite);
   nwrite+=n;
 }
 while( (n<0) && (errno==EINTR) );
```

and this is the receiver:

```
#define MAXSIZE 65536
.....
char buf[MAXSIZE];
nread=0;
do{ 
  n=read(socketfd, &(buf[nread]), MAXSIZE ) ;
  fflush(stdout);
  nread+=n;
}while( (n<0) && (errno==EINTR) );
```

It works if file_to_send weight is < than 65536 but if it's bigger I lose  parts of the text.
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I'm assuming this isn't the complete code, as you don't read anything into the buffer (and so the `strlen` call will be undefined).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes this isn't all , i've write only the part where there's the write and the read cause i think the problem is there...maybe

Comment: I don't understand the title. TCP sockets transfer byte streams not messages or packets.  TCP can easily transfer files greater than 64KB.  If there is a problem with losing data, it is in your understanding, protocol or implementation.

Comment: @MartinJames so what you are saying is that  I can declare the arrays msg and buf greater than 65536 and send all in one time? I assumed that I had to declare 65536 cause of the size of ip packet, is it wrong?

Comment: Martin James is correct - packet size is not a limiting factor. Also packets on the ethernet are 1500 bytes (raw, data size will be smaller). Nonstandart Jumbo frames are biger ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumbo_frame ), yet smaller than 64KB.

Answer (score 1):

What's MAXSIZE?

In the receiver you are receiving MAXSIZE that could be bigger than the buffer itself.

You should be transfering the buffer to stdout in every loop, that way you always have space in the buffer for the next read.

```
char buf[65536];
nread=0;
do{ 
  n=read(socketfd, buf, 65536);
  if (n > 0) {
    n=write(stdout, buf, n);
    fflush(stdout);
    nread+=n;
  }
} while( (n>0) || (errno==EINTR) );
```

Also check Davide Berra 's answer to fix the loop condition in both sender and receiver.

Answer (score 0):

You got a problem with the `while` control.

If `write` function is successful, it will return a value `greater than 0`, then your loop will exit after the first write.

Roughly, you should change this line

```
 while( (n<0) && (errno==EINTR) );
```

with

```
 while( n>0 || error==EINTR );
```

...and the same for the `read` side

Comment: Though EINTR would still need to be coped with, or you'll potentially end up with less than desired.